# PostgreSQL - Running out of memory when restoring database from large dump

Tags: postgresql, restore, pg-dump

I have a Postgres database dump in text format, which is roughly 20GB. I am trying to restore the database using the command

```bash
$ psql DatabaseName < path-to-dump
```

But after I while I get the message `out of memory` and it stops. Is there something I can do to overcome this problem?

Note that I am running it in Ubuntu 20.04. My version of postgres is

```bash
$ /usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/postgres -V
output: postgres (PostgreSQL) 12.8 (Ubuntu 12.8-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

The dump has the following 2 lines in the beginning, regarding its version:

```
-- Dumped from database version 12.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.1 (Ubuntu 13.1-1.pgdg20.04+1)
```

Comment: You'll need to monitor resource consumption by Postgres, as the dump is being restored, to determine why it is running out of memory, then reconfigure it to resolve the problem.

Comment: I tried to see the resource consumption using `gnome-system-monitor`and only the CPU utilization increases. Is there any specific step I should take?

Comment: So you're saying that memory utilisation doesn't increase, and yet it runs out of memory; I'm not sure how to reconcile that. You probably want to use [some of these](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html)

Comment: Have you checked any of the [existing answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpostgres%5D+%22out+of+memory%22)?

Comment: Yes, I had checked the related questions/answers but I didn't find a solution. I will take a look at the statistics, thanks for the hint.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the error message?  Do you find any messages in the server's log file?

Comment: Yes that's the entirety of the message. I think the dump has some small typos because I was getting some warnings, but the restoration continues normally, until the `out of memory` message. The log file is 3GB. I tried to cat the last 10 lines using `tail -10 postgresql-12-main.log` but I didn't see any error there.

Comment: A dump taken by 13.1 might not replay into 12.8.  Try taking the dump with the correct version.

Comment: Does the 12.8 server have less RAM than the 12.5 server?

Comment: A shot in the dark: do you have lots of [large objects](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/largeobjects.html)?

Comment: @jjanes I don't think it's a RAM issue. Can you explain to me this part a bit? If the postgres version is 12.5, how was the dump taken from 13.1? Which version should I install so that the dump can be parsed correctly?

Comment: You can have multiple versions installed on the same machine.  So the database could be running with one version, while the pg_dump binary being used is from a different one.  Or pg_dump can be run from a different machine than what is running the database, by using the -h argument..